# How to append JavaScript to div in angular 5+?

Tags: javascript, angular, event-binding

I want to append htmlString in a div tag.

**app.component.ts** file,

```
public htmlString:string = '';

this.htmlString:string = '<img id="img" src="assets/imgages/image.jpg">
<script>
  document.getElementById("img").onclick = function(){
      alert('click on image');
  };
</script>';
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div></div>
```

I have used below code but script return as a plain text.

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlString"></div>
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Angular ignores the `<script>` tag altogether. From the [`docs`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax):

> HTML is the language of the Angular template. Almost all HTML syntax
>   is valid template syntax. The `<script>` element is a notable exception;
>   it is forbidden, eliminating the risk of script injection attacks. In
>   practice, `<script>` is ignored and a warning appears in the browser
>   console

To display content based on a *click* event you can do something similar to:

.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  displayData: boolean;
  content: string = 'Something to be displayed on click event';

  appendData() {
    this.displayData = true;
  }
}
```

.html

```
<img id="img" src="assets/imgages/image.jpg" (click)="appendData()">

<div *ngIf="displayData">
  {{content}}
</div>
```

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ze9jhw) for the same.

Comment: Edited the answer to include a *trivial* example. (The code shared can be made shorter but it's easier to read)

Comment: If Angular is prohibiting it; then IMO it's for a reason and I don't think we should try to  bypass it.

Comment: If the answer helped you; do consider upvoting/accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a simple workaround you can try like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div (click)="showAlert()">
  <div [innerHtml]="htmlString"></div>
</div>
```

**TS**:

```
 htmlString: any = '<img id="img" src="assets/imgages/image.jpg">'

 showAlert(){
    alert('click on image');
 }
```